# Encoding using apache commons

Tags: java

I am trying to change from this proprietary

```
private String getSecWebSocketAccept(String secKey) 
    throws UnsupportedEncodingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {
    String guid = "258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11";
    secKey += guid;
    MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
    md.update(secKey.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), 0, secKey.length());
    byte[] shalHash = md.digest();
    BASE64Encoder encoder = new BASE64Encoder();
    return encoder.encode(shalHash);
}
```

encoding to apache version

> org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64

but it simply wont work when i try

```
private String getSecWebSocketAccept(String secKey) 
    throws UnsupportedEncodingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {
    String guid = "258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11";
    secKey += guid;
    MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
    md.update(secKey.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), 0, secKey.length());
    byte[] shalHash = md.digest();
    org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.encodeBase64 encoder = new org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.encodeBase64();
    return encoder.encode(shalHash);
}
```

This is the error i get

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\html>javac SimpleServer.java
SimpleServer.java:87: error: cannot find symbol
                org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.encodeBase64 encoder = ne
w org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.encodeBase64();
                                                      ^
  symbol:   class encodeBase64
  location: class Base64
SimpleServer.java:87: error: cannot find symbol
                org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.encodeBase64 encoder = ne
w org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.encodeBase64();

                                        ^
  symbol:   class encodeBase64
  location: class Base64
2 errors
```

Comment: Try to change import and jar.

Comment: This is my import import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
and the jar is in the classpath.

Comment: A `new` too much. Mind, there are several public Base64 implementations in standard Java (EE): `byte[] bytes = DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(data);` from `java.xml.bind`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.encodeBase64`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.html#encodeBase64%28byte%5B%5D%29) is a static method. Use it like this:

```
byte[] encoded = Base64.encodeBase64(shalHash);
```

In additon, you can use [`org.apache.commons.codec.digest.DigestUtils.sha1(byte[] data)`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/codec/digest/DigestUtils.html#sha1%28byte%5B%5D%29):

```
byte[] shalHash = DigestUtil.sha1(secKey.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"));
```